# weak variable assigned to strong variable in objective c

Tags: objective-c

what will happen if weak variable is assigned to strong variable . Will the strong gets released when weak goes out of scope , will it create a memory leak ? As per my assumption compiler will add release statement for the strong variable in ARC mode and it will not create memory leak . Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign a variable to an other one, you assign the value of a variable to an other variable. So your strong variable will "retain" your object.